# Safari View Controller URL/Navigation box (text field) color

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, sfsafariviewcontroller

**Preface:**

- I'm using `SFSafariViewController` to login to Steam.
- I'm trying to customise the `SFSafariViewController`.

**What I've got so far:**

- I'm developing the app for iOS 10, which allows both `preferredControlTintColor`and `preferredBarTintColor`.

[image]

As you can notice the **URL/Navigation box (text field)** is almost white.
I would like to change this color to the same as the `BarTintColor`.

**Optional**

- When `SFSafariViewController` is presented, there are a few milliseconds before the URL is loaded, during which the background color is white. I would also like to change this to a darker color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Per Apple's documentation on SFSafariViewController, there is no way to change URL/Navigation box (text field) color. Apple suggests that you use WKWebView if you need a custom browser interface (I also used same).